# How can I get my app version from app store programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, app-store

How can I get my app version number from app store programmatically? 
And is it against the HIG that if I show an alert to user that I've released an update? will apple accept if I show an alert for each and every update of my app in appstore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely not discouraged, just slightly annoying, especially when creating immersive experiences like games.  But anyways, here is a controls specifically made for your specific needs: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/iversion